# Backup and Restore Cassandra On Kubernetes

Tags: cassandra, kubernetes

We have a Cassandra Cluster on my kubernetes cluster. How we are planning migrate the current cluster from GCP to AWS. How can I restore my Cassandra Keyspaces and Snapshots. From the following link, I got a idea for took backup:
https://8kmiles.com/blog/cassandra-backup-and-restore-methods/

But the docs shows only snapshot backup case. Nothing says about 'Keyspaces'. How can I backup my Keyspace and Snapshot.? How can I retore the same. Our Cassandra running on Kubernetes both GCP and AWS.

Comment: Why don't you just add a [new DC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html)?

Comment: After adding a new DC you can decommission the old dc https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options here:

1. a backup/restore approach as you stated. Be aware that `nodetool snapshot` is copying your data and exports the schema of the table in `schema.cql` file. You will need to run a `describe keyspace` command on the existing cluster and run it on the new cluster in order to create the new keyspace, since nodetool is not doing this. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650770/nodetool-snapshot-takes-schema-snapshot-backup-too) has some details regarding this matter.
2. Add a [new DC](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html) and [decommission](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html) the old one, after the data is migrated. Here you must have the same cassandra version.

Comment: Please note that my cassandra cluster in kubernetes. I have already backup the Keyspace,Schema and Snapshot. But I dont know how can I restore the "Keyspace,Schema and Snapshot". I tried with the following link: https://medium.com/@adriagalin/import-and-export-keyspace-or-schema-in-cassandra-a7aa23c7092c  and the Schema/keyspace created in new spaces,but the keyspaces seems empty. Please help

Comment: In the link that you provided the instructions are just for restoring the keyspace and the schema (the structure of the tables) and not the actual data. [Here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001593706-Manual-Backup-and-Restore-with-Point-in-time-and-table-level-restore-) you will find how to actually restore the data. This applies also on k8s (of course, if you use persistent volumes :) )

Answer (score 0):

Use an ETL e.g. Spark job to pipe the data from one cloud to the other

Comment: Can we use Spark Job to read entire cluster of 6 nodes with 400GB of data and write to another cluster and in our case While source cluster is active , what are the memory and CPU overhead if we use Spark to Read , is it really good idea to run Spark job on entire table copy without using partition keys

Comment: @ravi Spark can handle the traffic (yo can use dataproc on GCP). make sure cassandra can handle. Memory and CPU and traffic will be expensive. Create a mirror da in AWS and just move the data by queries, using the exact same scheme and partitioning.